# How do I cover a transparent layer in Photoshop with black?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop, image-editing

In Photoshop CS4, I created a new completely transparent layer. I then selected the entire canvas and right-clicked to fill it up with a color.

However, I received the following error:

> Could not move selection because the selected area is empty.

Of course, the area is empty, but that is why I selected the area; to fill it up with a color. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make black your background color, by pressing <kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd>. Select the transparent layer.

[image]

Then, press

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> on Windows
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> on OS X

to fill the layer with the selected background color.

[image]

To do the same, using the foreground color, use <kbd>alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while doing so will also preserve transparency values.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. Also, do you know how to select all the transparent areas of a png image efficiently in Photoshop?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean, but you can Ctrl-click the layer thumbnail to select all visible pixels, and then inverse the selection with `Ctrl-Shift-I`.